# How to change the elements of spacing in text

Tags: html, css, text

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/line-height

This is what I found on line height. Im trying to add spaces in between indivual letters though.

So I guess in terms of the question Im asking, its not horizontal attributes, its vertical.

So something L I K E  T H I S

As you noting, (LIKE THIS) above is spaced differently. Whats the attribute in css to determine the spacing values.

Comment: You [didn't search](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=cgozVuOdBvHI8AebzrbADw&gws_rd=ssl#q=css+add+spaces+in+between+indivual+letters) hard enough for *"Im trying to add spaces in between indivual letters"*

Comment: I actually did search, but that too Im bad at. whats wrong with asking stack over google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    h1 {
        letter-spacing: 5px;
    }

    h2 {
        letter-spacing: -10px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>Like This</h1>
    <h2>Like This</h2>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `letter-spacing`

```css
p{
  letter-spacing:10px
}
```

```html
<p>hello How are you ?</p>
```

for details go with link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing

Comment: I also realized there's word spacing. Interesting. Im new to code, sorry about asking. But thanks for the answers